# Is this the correct way of setting up the database tables for like functionality?

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to make it so that the users could like images. The user would only be able to like, no disliking. Currently I see it happening this way.

I'll have 3 tables.

```
Table: Images
Columns: id, title, user_id, file_name

Table: Users
Columns: id, username, password

Table: Likes
Columns: id, image_id, user_id, liked
```

When a user likes an image, I'll have a record inserted into the `likes` table with the:

- `id` of the image which has been liked
- `id` of the user who has liked it
- and have the `liked` field set to true, indicating that the image has
  been liked by the user.

The thing which is bugging me is that even though `liked` is gonna be a boolean, it will never be set to false since if the image is not liked, there's not gonna be a record in the table and if the image is liked, `liked` will be set to true.

This is why I'm wondering if this is the correct way to set the table.

Comment: `liked` does not make sense. The presence of the row is the like. Up/downvotes would be another case where an indicator field could make sense.

Comment: So it should be Like only?

Comment: A simple table `image_id`, `user_id`

Comment: Ahhh so the Liked column shouldn't exists at all?

Comment: What should it do? You do not want an entry for 1'000'000 images multiplied by 10'000 users and update the DB with many entries each time a new user is registred or a new image is uploaded. So `liked` will always be true. A single entry is inserted when a user likes an image. Or, as said above, if you want likes and dislikes, then you can use a field to distinguish that.

Comment: Yes I suppose that is true. I guess I would only need a column like that if there was a like AND dislike functionality.